# Why is my plot pale?

Tags: plotting

I have a problem with the following ParametricPlot:

```
ParametricPlot[
 ReIm[(1 + I) (x + I y)],
 {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
 Mesh -> None,
 PlotPoints -> {50, 50},
 MaxRecursion -> 3,
 Axes -> None,
 PlotStyle -> {Texture[img4], Opacity[1]},
 BoundaryStyle -> None,
 Frame -> None
  ]
```

(This code should simply turn the chessboard-like tiling by Pi/4 and scale it.)
The original texture looks as one would expect (saturated black, white). Why does the output image look so pale (despite the `Opacity[1]` command)?

I am probably missing something obvious but lots of trying different approaches did not solve the problem. Thanks for your help!

[image]

Here is the original texture:

[image]

Comment: Please supply the texture image. I created my own one with `img4 = ImageResize[
   Image[Table[Mod[1 + j + Mod[i, 2], 2], {i, 1, 16}, {j, 1, 16}]], 
   512];` and the image looks fine.

Comment: I added the original file. Unfortunately, your approach results in exactly the same pale image for me. (Both my original file and your adaption look good before transformation.)
Meanwhile, I noticed that the paleness vanishes (i.e. the picture looks just fine) if I export the transformed image to pdf. If I export to png, the problem stays.

Comment: What version are you on? Your image works for me on 12.3.1 (Windows 10). It's probably a bug if you have an older version. If you do `Rasterize` on your `ParametricPlot` does it produce a good image?

Comment: Rasterize has no effect neither. It is version 12.0.0.0 (Linux), so I probably should contact the system administrator and hope that an update does the deal. Thank you for your advise so far :)

Comment: @hieron Maybe that would work as a workaround for this specific problem. But since I want to transform the image in more complicated ways later on, your proposal is not suitable for me.

Comment: Why don*t you use Graphics

Comment: Using the supplied image, the result is not grayed out (V12.3.1): https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWMi1.png -- Does your image have an alpha channel not present in the imgur upload?

Comment: Alternative to texture: `ParametricPlot[ReIm[(1 + I) (x + I y)], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, Mesh -> 15, MeshShading -> Map[GrayLevel, 1 - IdentityMatrix[2], {2}], BoundaryStyle -> Thin, Axes -> None, Frame -> None]`. Variations: `Map[GrayLevel, IdentityMatrix[2], {2}]` or `BoundaryStyle -> None`.

Comment: Works fine for me.  (v.11.3, MacOS)

Comment: With Graphics `move[coord_] := 
  GeometricTransformation[#, TranslationTransform@coord] &;
turn[rotList_] := 
  GeometricTransformation[#, RotationTransform[Sequence @@ rotList]] &;
Graphics[{Texture[img4], 
  Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
    VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}] // 
   turn@{72 \[Degree]}}]`

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks for the new idea! As far as I know there is no difference between my used image and the imgur upload.
For this mapping your approach looks very nice to me but it seems to break down for more difficult mappings: https://i.stack.imgur.com/udfUR.png

Comment: @hieron Thank you, too! I am quite new to Mathematica, so your code looks a bit like hieroglyphs to me (but it works well). The problem for me is that I do not understand how I can implement transformations which are not affine linear by adapting your code.